# ms access query hangs

Tags: database, ms-access

**qFieldInner**

```
PARAMETERS pText1 Text ( 255 );
SELECT entries.en_main, MIN(entries.en_id) AS en_id
FROM entries
WHERE (((entries.en_main) In (625, 1310)))
GROUP BY en_main;
```

when i run this query it returns:

625  76719

1310 177239

however if I transform it to this:

```
PARAMETERS pText1 Text ( 255 );
SELECT entries.en_main, MIN(entries.en_id) AS en_id
FROM entries
WHERE (((entries.en_main) In (SELECT en_main FROM qFieldInnest)))
GROUP BY en_main;
```

then it just hangs.

**qFieldInnest** is this and correctly returns 625 and 1310 when i run it manually

```
PARAMETERS pText1 Text ( 255 );
SELECT DISTINCT entries.en_main
FROM entries
WHERE (((entries.en_lect) Like ("* " & [pText1] & "*") Or (entries.en_lect) Like ([pText1] & "*")) AND ((entries.en_ref)=0) AND (((entries.en_se)=1) OR ((entries.en_meros)=6))) OR (((entries.en_thama) Like ("* " & [pText1] & "*") Or (entries.en_thama) Like ([pText1] & "*")));
```

I can't understand what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would approach this with a query which uses the SQL from `qFieldInnest` as a subquery, and `INNER JOIN` the subquery to the `entries` table.

The `WHERE` clause in `qFieldInnest` is challenging for me to follow.  It will challenge the db engine, too, because of the amount of work it has to do.

I have nothing to test against, so uncertain whether I made mistakes in the following SQL.  If it doesn't work, break out the subquery SQL into a new query and test that separately.

```
PARAMETERS pText1 Text ( 255 );
SELECT e.en_main, MIN(e.en_id) AS en_id
FROM
    entries AS e
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT en_main
        FROM entries
        WHERE
                (
                    (
                           en_lect Like "* " & [pText1] & "*"
                        Or en_lect Like [pText1] & "*"
                    )
                    AND en_ref=0
                    AND
                        (
                               en_se=1
                            OR en_meros=6
                        )
                )
            OR
                (
                       en_thama Like "* " & [pText1] & "*"
                    Or en_thama Like [pText1] & "*"
                )

    ) AS sub
    ON e.en_main = sub.en_main
GROUP BY e.en_main;
```

Comment: what i don't understand is why <b>qFieldInnest</b> correctly returns 625 and 1310 after a couple of seconds when i run it manually through the db file but when i run manually the <b>qFieldInner</b> it seems to stuck. However if the values are hardcoded it works properly!

Comment: your version works properly just tested it. don't understand why.

Comment: `qFieldInnest` includes a complex demanding `WHERE` clause.  When run alone, the db engine can cope adequately.  But when incorporated into another query, the db engine chokes due to the added complexity.  In other situations, the db engine throws an error about "query too complex" because it can't cope.  My gut says something similar was happening with your original attempt, but without an error message.

Comment: Another factor is that `INNER JOIN` execution speed trumps `WHERE something IN (something else)`, in the majority of cases I've examined in detail.